# Struts ignoring validate method

Tags: java, struts, actionform

```
<form-bean name="RegisterForm" type="com.mysite.form.RegisterForm" />

<action path="/register" type="com.mysite.action.RegisterAction" name="RegisterForm" input="/register.jsp" validate="true">
                <forward name="success" path="/welcome.jsp" />
                <forward name="failure" path="/register.jsp" />
            </action>
```

**RegisterForm**

```
public class RegisterForm extends ActionForm{
private String name;

    /**
    Constructor
    Set+Get
    **/

    public ActionErrors validate(ActionMapping mapping, ServletRequest request) {

        ActionErrors errorList = new ActionErrors();
        System.out.println("VALIDATING");
        return errorList;
    }
}
```

This is all i have. For some reason it seems that the control flow jumps directly to the ActionForm's execute method because I can't even see the VALIDATING message in the console. Is there something I'm missing? Thanks!

Comment: Try to validate your action form with ValidatorForm instead of ActionForm and let me know the result.

Comment: The given code is not real code, because it doesn't compile (Public instead of public). Try adding the @Override annotation to the validate method, to make sure you're actually overriding the ActionForm's validate method. Also try to include an error in the ActionErrors: you might miss the VALIDATING message in the console.

Comment: @JBNizet it is real code but I edited it because there were a lot of validation and it didn't make any point to put those here. The methos is overriding the parent method.

Comment: @Naved it seems to work just fine with the ValidatorForm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the other overloaded validate() method that takes HttpServletRequest